# Open new terminal at in current directory

Tags: bash, macos-mojave

Using bash on MacOS Mojave, I want to open a terminal in the current directory and execute a command:

```
#!/bin/bash

osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"' -e 'do script "./something_to_run"' -e 'end tell'
```

The code above opens a new terminal window, but it does so at the root directory and not the directory the script above executed in. I guess I should use `pwd` somehow, but I am not sure how.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"' -e 'do script "cd '$(pwd)'"' -e 'end tell'`

Comment: @RobC Thanks, but this does not work. It gives a Syntax error. In any case, even if it did run, it would just open the terminal in the usual place, rather than in `PWD` because `PWD` would be reset upon opening the new terminal.

Also, as you can see in my question, I need to open the terminal in the current directory and then run a script

Comment: Interesting I don't get a syntax error. Perhaps you can clarify what you mean by _"current directory"_ and provide further context.

Comment: @RobC by `current directory` I mean the directory from which I call the above script.

Comment: `$(pwd)` should be in double quotes to avoid syntax errors or worse if the directory path has spaces or other special characters. It should be `"cd '"$(pwd)"\" -e 'end tell'`

Comment: @pookie it should work fine since the `pwd` runs in the current script not in the new terminal. Only the `cd` runs in the new terminal, but the `pwd` is in the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down'

osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "./script.sh" in window 1'
```

I found these commands from a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/un33k/597455/60b9913bb59712951121158f5487283890dbb39f). First command opens a tab in your existing terminal window and the second says do the script in that tab.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the question as follows:

You have a shell script which you want to open with a double-click in Finder and then a terminal should be opened in the directory where the shell script is located. In my case the above code only opens a terminal in the home directory.

However, the parameter `$0` passed to the shell script contains the command executed, which includes the current directory. Using `$dirname ($0)` gives the directory.

So I found the solution by the following command:

```
open -a "Terminal" "$(dirname "$0")"
```

Hope this helps